# VSCode annoying problem focus behavior, keeps jumping to a problem

Tags: visual-studio-code

Last Edit:

It appears I've had an F8 key being pressed non-stop, and it seems to be a shortcut for "Go to Next Error or Warning".

I've wrote a piece of code, it has an error which I'm aware of. Specifically, I'm trying to run a function which doesn't exist yet:

[image]

All good, I'm glad it is telling me there's a problem, but... I wish to keep writing stuff in the same file and I simply can't. Every so often the GUI keeps sending the caret (the place where my next piece of text will be written) to the beginning of the problematic piece of code. Simply speaking, I can't keep doing anything until I resolve the problem, since it forcefully intrudes my every action. Even more than that! When I go to a different file, with means of fixing the problem and adding the missing function, it once again interrupts me and forcefully takes me back to the problematic file to show me that there's a problem (??!?!?!). Closing it with "Esc" only closes it once, but it keeps on returning every several seconds.

I don't think it was like that just a week ago, and I didn't install any new plugin since then. I'm currently using the last version, 1.58.2.

How do I stop this work-flow-intruding behavior?

Edit:
I've kept on working for some time and it turns out the issue is much bigger than that. Whenever I type a name of some property, half way through some wild problem would jump and tell me "Cannot find name 'quar'. Did you mean 'quarter'?". The issue is basically the time delay of the problem checks, it's non-existent. It's also too intrusive, moving the caret and jumping between files to show me the existing problems. It's very recent, it didn't happen earlier this week. I've tried disabling different plugins I have and they're not the cause.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly your issue, but could be related to what you are experiencing: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68776

Try disabling the ***Outline Explorer*** and see what happens then.

[image]

Furthermore, see if ***disabling autosave*** improves anything.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, and it's very specific to my pc and my previous actions, so both the problem and the solution aren't reproducible. I'll be deleting my question in a couple of minutes

Comment: Thank you for your time and input, I appreciate it

Comment: Nevermind, I can't delete it since it was answered... Will have to edit it